# Can ffmpeg convert to qcp purevoice format?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, conversion

Is there a way to convert audio files to [Qualcom's QCP PureVoice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QCP) format in ffmpeg? I get

```
> ffmpeg -i file.mp3 file.qcp
> "Unable to find a suitable output format for file.qcp"
```

Why? I have an old flip phone and that is the only audio format it understands for non-midi ringtones. I realize that [dedicated software](http://purevoice.software.informer.com/2.4/) exists to do this but it would be great if I could do it with ffmpeg since I use that for many other conversions as well.

Comment: FFmpeg does not appear to have a dedicated QCP muxer.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard out of curiosity, say I wanted to write one, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Get the FFmpeg source code and take a look at some other simple audio muxers in the `libavformat` directory. See the [FFmpeg Developer Documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/developer.html). You can hang out in #ffmpeg-devel IRC channel if you want to talk with developers and ask questions.